# Unhandled Exception: Deserializing

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, built-value

I am grabbing data from an online endpoint. I am using built_value for deserializing JSON. However I came to an error and I am stuck.This is the error I am getting:

```
Unhandled Exception: Deserializing '[count, 2, results, [{id: 2, name: Upload Purchase orders, kpi: {id: 2, name:...' to 'TasksListResponseJModel' failed due to: Deserializing '[{id: 2, name: Upload Purchase orders, kpi: {id: 2, name: kpi}, assign: {id: ...' to 'BuiltList<Taskresult>' failed due to: Deserializing '[id, 1, name, Telkom, kpi, {id: 1, name: Telkom}, assign, {id: 2, name: cha c...' to 'Taskresult' failed due to: Deserializing '[tag]' to 'BuiltList<Tags>' failed due to: Deserializing 'tag' to 'Tags' failed due to: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' in type cast
```

**The JSON**:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Upload Purchase orders",
            "kpi": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "kpi"
            },
            "assign": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "cha cha"
            },
            "team": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Commercial"
            },
            "site": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Soi"
            },
            "status": "Todo",
            "tags": [],
            "subtasks": [],
            "progress": 0,
            "files": [],
            "comments": []
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Telkom",
            "kpi": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Telkom"
            },
            "assign": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "cha cha"
            },
            "team": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Commercial"
            },
            "site": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "kasa"
            },
            "status": "Todo",
            "tags": [
                "tag"
            ],
            "subtasks": [],
            "progress": 0,
            "files": [],
            "comments": []
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the way I implemented the model:

My **Tasks_Model.dart**

```
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
part 'TasksListResponseJModel.g.dart';


 abstract class TasksListResponseJModel implements Built<TasksListResponseJModel, TasksListResponseJModelBuilder> {

   static Serializer<TasksListResponseJModel> get serializer => _$tasksListResponseJModelSerializer;
   TasksListResponseJModel._();
   @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'count')
   int get count;
   @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'next')
   String get next;
   @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'previous')
   String get previous;
   @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'results')
   BuiltList<Taskresult> get results;


   factory TasksListResponseJModel([void Function(TasksListResponseJModelBuilder) updates]) = _$TasksListResponseJModel;

}

abstract class Taskresult implements Built<Taskresult, TaskresultBuilder> {
  Taskresult._();

  factory Taskresult([updates(TaskresultBuilder b)]) = _$Taskresult;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id')
  int get id;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'name')
  String get name;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'kpi')
  Kpi get kpi;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'assign')
  Assign get assign;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'team')
  Team get team;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'site')
  Site get site;


  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'progress')
  int get progress;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
  String get status;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'tags')
  BuiltList<Tags> get tags;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'subtasks')
  BuiltList<Subtasks> get subtasks;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'files')
  BuiltList<Files> get files;
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'comments')
  BuiltList<Comments> get comments;

  static Serializer<Taskresult> get serializer => _$taskresultSerializer;
}

abstract class Tags implements Built<Tags, TagsBuilder> {
  Tags._();

  factory Tags([updates(TagsBuilder b)]) = _$Tags;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'tag')
  String get tag;


  static Serializer<Tags> get serializer => _$tagsSerializer;
}

abstract class Subtasks implements Built<Subtasks, SubtasksBuilder> {
  Subtasks._();

  factory Subtasks([updates(SubtasksBuilder b)]) = _$Subtasks;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'subtask')
  String get subtask;

  static Serializer<Subtasks> get serializer => _$subtasksSerializer;
}

abstract class Files implements Built<Files, FilesBuilder> {
  Files._();

  factory Files([updates(FilesBuilder b)]) = _$Files;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'file')
  String get file;

  static Serializer<Files> get serializer => _$filesSerializer;
}

abstract class Comments implements Built<Comments, CommentsBuilder> {
  Comments._();

  factory Comments([updates(CommentsBuilder b)]) = _$Comments;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'comment')
  String get comment;

  static Serializer<Comments> get serializer => _$commentsSerializer;
}


abstract class Kpi implements Built<Kpi, KpiBuilder> {
  Kpi._();
  factory Kpi([void Function(KpiBuilder) updates]) = _$Kpi;


  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id')
  int get id;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'name')
  String get name;

  static Serializer<Kpi> get serializer => _$kpiSerializer;
}
abstract class Assign implements Built<Assign, AssignBuilder> {
  Assign._();
  static Serializer<Assign> get serializer => _$assignSerializer;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id')
  int get id;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'name')
  String get name;


  factory Assign([void Function(AssignBuilder) updates]) = _$Assign;
}

abstract class Site implements Built<Site, SiteBuilder> {
  Site._();
  static Serializer<Site> get serializer => _$siteSerializer;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id')
  int get id;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'name')
  String get name;

  factory Site([void Function(SiteBuilder) updates]) = _$Site;
}
abstract class Team implements Built<Team, TeamBuilder> {
  Team._();
  static Serializer<Team> get serializer => _$teamSerializer;

  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'id')
  int get id;
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'name')
  String get name;

  factory Team([void Function(TeamBuilder) updates]) = _$Team;
}
```

I have a FutureBuilder that retrieves the tasks here:

```
 Future<FutureBuilder<Response>> _buildBody(BuildContext context) async {
    return FutureBuilder<Response<BuiltList<TasksListResponseJModel>>>(
      future: Provider.of<ApiService>(context).getTasks(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                snapshot.error.toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textScaleFactor: 1.3,
              ),
            );
          }

          final posts = snapshot.data.body;
          return _buildPosts(context, posts);
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I would really appreciate an explanation on where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because one of your attribute is defined as string but at runtime it is not a string that is coming from the response.Please check all the attribute data types defined correctly.In json Serialisation we have to put all data types correctly otherwise at run time serialisation will be failed.

ex:
int get count; is defined in the abstract class and incoming value from the json is
count:'2' (Is a String).That becomes an error in serialisation.

Also create separate dart files for each models(abstract classes).

```
BuiltList<Tags> get tags; It is not true here because In your response was a List<String> so It should be BuiltList<String> get tags;
```

Check Other data types if after corrected this.